# Cannot extract PSVersion string from $PSVersionTable

Tags: string, powershell

I have the following output :

```powershell
PS> $PSVersionTable

Name                           Value
----                           -----
CLRVersion                     2.0.50727.8806
BuildVersion                   6.1.7601.17514
PSVersion                      2.0
WSManStackVersion              2.0
PSCompatibleVersions           {1.0, 2.0}
SerializationVersion           1.1.0.1
PSRemotingProtocolVersion      2.1
```

I'd like to get `PSVersion` value as a string like this into a variable : `2.0`

So I tried this but it's not what I want :

```powershell
PS> $PSVersionTable.PSVersion

Major  Minor  Build  Revision
-----  -----  -----  --------
2      0      -1     -1
```

and these commands :

EDIT0 : I had copied'n'pasted the wrong line but still the string concatenation didn't work :

```powershell
PS> $myVariable = $PSVersionTable.PSVersion.Major + "." + $PSVersionTable.PSVersion.Minor
Cannot convert value "." to type "System.Int32". Error: "Input string was not in a correct format."
At line:1 char:48
+ $myVariable = $PSVersionTable.PSVersion.Major + <<<<  "." + $PSVersionTable.PSVersion.Minor
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : RuntimeException

PS> $PSVersionTable | Select-Object PSVersion

PSVersion
---------



PS> $PSVersionTable | Get-Item PSVersion
Get-Item : The input object cannot be bound to any parameters for the command either because the command does not take pipeline input or the input and its properties do
not match any of the parameters that take pipeline input.
At line:1 char:27
+ $PSVersionTable | Get-Item <<<<  PSVersion
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (System.Collections.Hashtable:Hashtable) [Get-Item], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InputObjectNotBound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetItemCommand
```

I'm a powershell rookie, can you help me ?

Comment: use the `.ToString()` method. something like this >>> `($PSVersionTable).PSVersion.ToString()` <<<

Comment: @Lee_Dailey Thanks a lot, can u convert your comment to an answer?

Comment: i see that `Steven`  has Answered you. glad to have helped a bit & to see that you got it working as needed! [*grin*]

Comment: @Lee_Dailey I also thank for your help. God bless you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the `.ToString()` method on the PSVersion key's value.

```
$MyVariable = $PSVersionTable.PSVersion.ToString()
```

Or:

```
$MyVariable = $PSVersionTable[ "PSVersion" ].ToString()
```

Note: The different syntax is because $PSVersion is a hash table or a dictionary object.  PowerShell lets you use either syntax.  Your executing the method on the value that's returned.

`$MyVariable` will be a string like "2.0".  I double checked in version 5.1 and got "5.1.19041.546".  If you want to isolate just the major version you can do it like:

```
$MyVariable = $PSVersionTable.PSVersion.Major
```

But this won't give you the minor point version.

You could also do something like:

```
$PSVersionTable.PSVersion.Major,$PSVersionTable.PSVersion.Minor -join "."
```

This will return "5.1" in my case. So, just major & minor versions but dropping build and revision information.  It works by formatting the 2 values into an array and joining them into a string on a "."

**Note regarding your question:**

The first error is due to PowerShell's type conversion system.  This is a little more complex to explain here, but PowerShell will attempt to convert data types to complete operations.  It's intuitive but not perfect, and in this case it can't convert the "." to a number.  One thing to point out is the tendency to convert the right side to the type of the left.  Below would work.

```
$PSVersionTable.PSVersion.Major.ToString() + "." + $PSVersionTable.PSVersion.Minor
```

Above manually converts the left to a string so there is no trouble concatenating with ".", when the second "+" is evaluated the Right side is easily converted from `[Int32]` to `[String]`, so it will work.

In this case I would prefer to use casting like:

```
[String]$PSVersionTable.PSVersion.Major + "." + $PSVersionTable.PSVersion.Minor
```

Effectively this is the same, but I prefer it from a syntax perspective.

The `select` command doesn't work because you are sending the hash table down the pipe and technically there is no "PSVersion" property to select.  A correction to that might look something like:

```
$PSVersionTable.GetEnumerator() | 
Where-Object{ $_.Name -eq "PSVersion" } | 
Select-Object value
```

Obviously this is less convenient than other solutions, but I included it for illustration.

The third problem is just not a correct command or syntax.  `Get-Item` cannot take the `$PSVerrsionTable` hashtable as input, piped or otherwise.

Comment: Regarding the missing `$` I had copied'n'pasted the wrong line but still the string concatenation didn't work : see my EDIT0

Comment: See your edit. For completeness I will update my answer.

Comment: Oh I see, it cannot concatenate integers and strings :)

Comment: It can provided it can get through a type conversion.  a string like "32" would easily convert to an [Int], but ".". cannot...  I'd recommend you read through Chapter 3 of "PowerShell In Action" by Bruce Payette.  It will describe these behaviors pretty well, and certainly enough that you'd immediately recognize this type of problem and easily get past it.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your detailed answer :+1:

Comment: Just one very last thing : given that `$PSVersionTable.PSVersion` contains `2      0      -1     -1`, why does `echo $PSVersionTable` shows `2.0` for `PSVersion` instead of `2.0.-1.-1` ?

Comment: I think that has to do with the [type] of that property.  The property PSVersion  is type System.Version and the -1's indicate build & revision info wasn't populated.  You can a test like `@{TestVersion = New-Object -TypeName System.Version -ArgumentList 2,0 }` you'll get a similar result.  PowerShells for-display formatting system is likely running the `.ToString()` on PSVersion to display the hash as a table.  If you did the same on the above example you'd get "2.0" eventhough the tabled display of System.Version by itself would be 2 0 -1 -1 ...

Comment: OK I see. Is there an equivalent to the Python `type` command which shows me the type of the objet I'm looking at ?

Comment: Much of the literature suggests using ` | Get-Member` this will list the type along with the properties, methods and other members of the object.  However, it can be verbose, so I prefer to use the universal `.GetType()` method. `$PSVersionTable.GetType()` and/or `$PSVersionTable.GetType().FullName`.  You can either test that which you discover or use to further research on MS Docs etc to better understand the object.